# control getting NULL value on findcontrol

Tags: xml, reference, null, findcontrol

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="rgdProductLine" AutoGenerateColumns="False" runat="server">
 <MasterTableView CommandItemDisplay="Top" EditMode="InPlace" Caption="Products">
           <CommandItemTemplate>                  
                     <telerik:RadToolBar ID="RadToolBar1" runat="server" Skin="Windows7">
                   <Items>
                     <telerik:RadToolBarButton Text="Add"  CommandName="InitInsert" ImageUrl="Images/add.png" NavigateUrl="#"></telerik:RadToolBarButton>                                                  
                     <telerik:RadToolBarButton Text="Delete" CommandName="DeleteSelected" ImageUrl="Images/cross.png" NavigateUrl="#">
                     </telerik:RadToolBarButton>
                   </Items>
                        </telerik:RadToolBar>
             </CommandItemTemplate>
  </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

RadToolBar tb = rgdProductLine.MasterTableView.FindControl ("RadToolBar1") as RadToolBar;

on this function call,  'tb' is Null. also tried with rgdProductLine.MasterTableView.GetItems(GridItemType.CommandItem);  why so? thanks in adv.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code snippet.

```
 GridItem cmdItem = RadGrid1.MasterTableView.GetItems(GridItemType.CommandItem)[0];
    RadToolBar RadToolBar1 = cmdItem.FindControl("RadToolBar1") as RadToolBar;

    //OR


    GridCommandItem cmdItem = RadGrid1.MasterTableView.GetItems(GridItemType.CommandItem)[0] as GridCommandItem;
    RadToolBar RadToolBar1 = cmdItem.FindControl("RadToolBar1") as RadToolBar;
```

Note : If above code is not worked for you then please provide information in which event you try to get commanditem.